# JDT Compiler Exception

Tags: java, jsf, jboss, icefaces

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.CompilationResult.getProblems()[Lorg/eclipse/jdt/core/compiler/IProblem;
 at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler$2.acceptResult(JDTCompiler.java:329)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.handleInternalException(Compiler.java:502)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:430)
 at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:387)
 at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:288)
 at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:267)
 at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:255)
```

I am getting the above exception... any ideas?

1. JBoss (MX MicroKernel) [4.2.3.GA
2. JDK 1.6
3. Icefaces 1.8.2

Answer (score 0):

[here](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/RulesTomcat) is your solution

> JBoss Rules uses the Apache JCI to interface to compilers which means we can switch to other compilers or versions.
>
> There are several ways to enable the Janino compiler instead of JDT for Java semantics.